# Можно ли создать некое подобие исполняемого файла, который при запуске будет делегировать работу запущенному процессу

Tags: linux, файлы, процесс

Можно ли сделать так, чтоб при запуске процесс создавал "исполняемый файл". К примеру, создать фоновый процесс, который будет создавать несколько файлов, как будто это обычный исполняемый файл, и при их запуске `./имя файла` или через `exec` данный процесс будет выполнять работу, связанную с этими файлами.

Comment: Непонятно) Попробуйте перефразировать.

Comment: можно сделать, что `./имя файла` будет обычным скриптом, который запускает твою программу с определёнными параметрами, потом она связывается с уже работающим процессом через какой-нить сокет и отправляет ему сигнал выполнять какую-либо деятельность...